# oracle pctfree calculation for a segment

Tags: row, storage, oracle12c

How can i calculate the right pctfree on a given oracle table. Is there a standard way to do this?

For example if I have a table with 15 columns. Now if I insert data into this table. Average row length will be set. Now if I add new columns and update the existing rows with some values. will this cause row migration if there is not enough free space?

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be mentioned that nowadays you should not take care of such things as the size of PCTFREE or PCTUSED.

There's a perfect thing called Automatic Segment Space Manager Management (ASSM), which does all the dirty job for you. Since you tagged this question as "oracle12c" I assume you're running on a modern version of Oracle database and should not have any problem using ASSM. You can read more about it here: [Managing Tablespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tspaces.htm#ADMIN011)

Now, back to your question. If you still want to know how to manually calculate PCTFREE and PCTUSED, then you should have a look at this Tom Kyte's answer : [Calculating the PCTFREE and PCTUSED](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:733825532206)

> if I add new columns and update the existing rows with some values.
>   will this cause row migration if there is not enough free space

Yes, if a row does not fit into a block along with other rows, it will be migrated.